# Does a bottom tab need its own separate stack

Tags: react-native

When navigating to a screen from my second bottom tab(tab2), the app switches to tab1 and then navigates to the screen. When you click on the text to change screens, you can see the tab1 screen flash right before it swipes to the page.

**How can I stay on the tab I am navigating from?** I want to navigate to screen3 while keeping  the tab on tab2.

**Why is it changing tabs upon navigation?**

To reproduce the bug... Click Tab2 -> click the text -> and you can see the bottom tab switch and the tab1 screen flashing before going to screen3.

Here is a [snack code](https://snack.expo.dev/@priedejm/0b3e59) reproducing my project exactly along with my app.js below.

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function MyTabs() {
  return (

    <Stack.Navigator
     initialRouteName="Home">        
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component= {Home} options={{headerShown: false}}/>
      <Stack.Screen name="Screen1" component= {Screen1} options={{headerShown: false}}/> 
      <Stack.Screen name="Screen2" component= {Screen2} options={{headerShown: false}}/>
      <Stack.Screen name="Screen3" component= {Screen3} options={{headerShown: false}}/>
    </Stack.Navigator>
);
}


export default function App() {

  return (
   <NavigationContainer>
    <Tab.Navigator
    initialRouteName="Tab1"
    screenOptions={{
      tabBarActiveTintColor: 'white',
      tabBarInactiveTintColor: '#4d4d4d',
      tabBarStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#d1cfcf',
        borderTopColor: 'transparent',
      },
    }} 
  >
    <Tab.Screen
      name="Tab1"
      component={MyTabs}
      options={{
        tabBarLabel: 'Tab1',
        headerShown: false,
        tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
          <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={size} />
        ),
      }}
    />
     <Tab.Screen
      name="Tab2"
      component={Screen2}
      options={{
        tabBarLabel: 'Tab2',
        headerShown: false,
        tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
          <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={size} />
        ),
      }}
    />
    
  </Tab.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
);
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
```

Comment: each Tab.Navigator should have its own Stack.Navigator, try creating an additional Stack.Navigator and pass it inside the component prop of Tab2 like you did for Tab1.

Comment: @Hugo If you want the bounty create an answer!

Comment: didn't see this on time, hope it helped anyway!

Comment: Fixed my issue! Sorry the bounty went elsewhere:( I wasn't sure if you would return to this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your demo code, navigating to `screen1` shows the bottomTabBar at the bottom, is this your required use case or a bug. I am assuming that it is bug and you don't want that.

To achieve that , it is recommended to use screens first and then BottomTabs. So define your bottomTabs in `screen1` then your existing code works as you want it.

your `App` should return

```
    <NavigationContainer>
   <Stack.Navigator
     initialRouteName="Tabs">        
      <Stack.Screen name="Tabs" component= {MyTabs} options={{headerShown: false}}/>
      <Stack.Screen name="Screen1" component= {Screen1} options={{headerShown: false}}/> 
      <Stack.Screen name="Screen2" component= {Screen2} options={{headerShown: false}}/>
      <Stack.Screen name="Screen3" component= {Screen3} options={{headerShown: false}}/>
    </Stack.Navigator>
```

your `MyTabs` function should return

```
<Tab.Navigator
    initialRouteName="Home"
    screenOptions={{
      tabBarActiveTintColor: 'white',
      tabBarInactiveTintColor: '#4d4d4d',
      tabBarStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#d1cfcf',
        borderTopColor: 'transparent',
      },
    }} 
  >
    <Tab.Screen
      name="Home"
      component={Home}
      options={{
        tabBarLabel: 'Tab1',
        headerShown: false,
        tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
          <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={size} />
        ),
      }}
    />
     <Tab.Screen
      name="Tab2"
      component={Screen2}
      options={{
        tabBarLabel: 'Tab2',
        headerShown: false,
        tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
          <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={size} />
        ),
      }}
    />
    
  </Tab.Navigator>
```

Working snack code is [here](https://snack.expo.dev/OLhguLg2P)

**Edit**: for bottomTabs to be visible even after navigation, you should create another Stacknavigator as you did for Tab1.
your code should look something like this,

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function MyTabs() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={Home}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Screen1"
        component={Screen1}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Screen2"
        component={Screen2}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Screen3"
        component={Screen3}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
function MySecondTabs() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Screen2">
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={Home}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Screen1"
        component={Screen1}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Screen2"
        component={Screen2}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Screen3"
        component={Screen3}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Tab1"
        screenOptions={{
          tabBarActiveTintColor: 'white',
          tabBarInactiveTintColor: '#4d4d4d',
          tabBarStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#d1cfcf',
            borderTopColor: 'transparent',
          },
        }}>
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Tab1"
          component={MyTabs}
          options={{
            tabBarLabel: 'Tab1',
            headerShown: false,
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
              <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={size} />
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Tab2"
          component={MySecondTabs}
          options={{
            tabBarLabel: 'Tab2',
            headerShown: false,
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
              <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={size} />
            ),
          }}
        />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

working snack [code](https://snack.expo.dev/B-aVRV8Wcd)

Comment: that actually isn't exactly what I want. I want the bottom tab to be on Screen3, but as you can see in my demo, the bottom tab switches to tab1 when you navigate to screen3 rather than staying on tab2. I think Hugo's comment above fixes this, I just havent had the time to implement it yet to check. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: ohh, if the bottomTabs should be visible in screen3 after navigation then you have follow Hugo's comment. Create another Stack Navigator for Tab2 just like you did for Tab1.